# How to post opengraph objects

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

Need help understanding how opengraph works and how it relates to the "FB Like" button.

We do have opengraph meta tags deployed on all of the pages for our content. However
it looks like the only way to get "FB Like" button to work, is to run the URL thru the facebook linter.

If a user attempts to "Like" the page, that was never liked before, only the URL will be posted to the wall.

If the url is ran thru the linter, all the consecutive likes will work properly, by image, title and description will be pulled.

- is it possible that the app_id is not linking properly with the pages?
- having our FB Admin go and like all the content that is produced is not an option

http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/travel/underwater-photos-amazing-shots-sea-gallery-1.1078782

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="366487756153">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1594068001">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NY Daily News">                            
<meta property="og:title" content="Mark Tipple's Underwater Project - Underwater photos: Amazing shots from under the sea">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/travel/underwater-photos-amazing-shots-sea-gallery-1.1078782">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.1078770!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/searchthumbnail_75/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Talented underwater photographer Mark Tipple, from Sydney, Australia, lies in wait for unsuspecting swimmers and surfers before snapping a perfect picture of them from beneath the waves.">
```

http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/john-travolta-experienced-bed-passionate-hotel-romp-claims-masseur-luis-gonzalez-article-1.1079272

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="366487756153">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1594068001">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="NY Daily News">                            
<meta property="og:title" content="John Travolta was 'a great kisser' and &lsquo;very experienced&rsquo; in bed during passionate hotel romp, claims masseur Luis Gonzalez&nbsp;">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nydailynews.com/gossip/john-travolta-experienced-bed-passionate-hotel-romp-claims-masseur-luis-gonzalez-article-1.1079272">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.1079279!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/searchthumbnail_75/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Another hotel masseur is claiming sexual shenanigans on the part of John Travolta -- only this accuser says he welcomed the actor's horny horseplay and found him &quot;very experienced&quot; in bed.">
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get your page recognized as a custom open graph object you'll need to follow these steps.

- Create a facebook app
- Setup site domain, namespace etc...
- Create a custom action and a custom object under app settings >> Open Graph: Getting Started ([see this link for help](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/))
- After creating it, you'll see your object under object types in Open Graph Settings
- Click on "Get Code" button to get the html tags
- Update your page to show up the same html head & meta tags
- Go to http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug to test if you have setup everything right

P.S. Don't forget to hit correct answer if it works, or PM me for more help

Answer (score 0):

Your URL isn't set to the application as noted in the linter,

> Object at URL 'http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/travel/underwater-photos-amazing-shots-sea-gallery-1.1078782' of type 'article' is invalid because the domain 'www.nydailynews.com' is not allowed for the specified application id '366487756153'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/366487756153.

Add the proper domain to your settings and it should work.